# How Trigger System To Destroy all files on specified LVM password?

Tags: linux, lvm

I want to delete all files on LVM encrypted disk if specified password for example "1234" was entered. Is there any way to do it?

I've found other questions that would trigger the system on specified user password but I want to set it on LVM decrypt.

Comment: What other thread? Please reference it in your question

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this idea has already been implemented in the "[LUKS Nuke Patch](https://github.com/offensive-security/cryptsetup-nuke-keys)" which is installed by default on Kali (but not enabled by default).

Basically, it behaves exactly as you describe it (a specific password will trigger the deletion of the whole file-system at once).

You can find more information about its installation and set-up on [this page](https://www.kali.org/tutorials/emergency-self-destruction-luks-kali/) or [this one](https://www.kali.org/tutorials/nuke-kali-linux-luks/) or even [this page](https://hackingvision.com/2017/07/08/self-destructing-encrypted-luks-partitions-emergency-nuke-kali-linux/).

And, [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76630/luks-nuke-efficiency) is an interesting discussion about the security and the limits of this scheme.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a modified version of `cryptsetup` that at least overwrites the master key of the encrypted volume when the specific password is entered.

[Here's a source code patch to `cryptsetup` that adds such functionality.](https://github.com/offensive-security/cryptsetup-nuke-keys)

However, [you should also read this thread.](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258356) In a real-life scenario against a smart attacker that wants the data, you and the system will first be separated from each other, and the encrypted disk will be cloned (and possibly equipped with a write-blocker to save some time) before you get to do anything potentially destructive with it.